# Is it possible to use reflection for a private static variable in a DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

I'm trying to **change the value of a singleton in a DLL** for a project, a fix is coming in 2 months, but until then I want to use reflexion to change some settings into that singleton to keep working. I have access to the DLL's code, so I know the private members.

each time I try to use reflexion on the DLL class, I get a null value for the field. Am I missing something, or is reflexion simply impossible in between DLL?

```cs
var field = typeof(SingletonClass).GetField("_Instance", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
var customSettings = new SingletonClass();
// ...

field.SetValue(null, customSettings);
```

## Update

Add more code snippet as requested

my reflection

```cs
 private TeamCityLogger GetLoggerInstance()
 {
     // This will be empty
     var test = typeof(TeamCityLogger).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public); 

     // and this null
     var field = typeof(TeamCityLogger).GetField("_Instance", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

     if (field == null)
     {
         Log.Warn($"Could not override the teamcity logger, can't find _Instance in {typeof(TeamCityLogger)} teabox will log as normal");
         return null;
     }

     return (TeamCityLogger)field.GetValue(null);
 }
```

the code in the DLL

```cs
 public class TeamCityLogger
 {
     private static TeamCityLogger _Instance;

     // some other code ...

     internal static void Register()
     {
         if (_Instance != null)
         {
            LogRaw("TeamCityLogger already Registered");
            return;
         }

         _Instance = new TeamCityLogger();
     }
 }
```

Comment: If a previous version worked, just continue using it. If you need the faulty versions for any new functions/solutions, disable those or roll them back until you got a working example. 2 Months is not a long time to wait for an update.

Comment: This is a critical bug impacting all of our production, I don't care if it's not fancy, I need this to work in order to buy time to find a proper fix, and I'm not sure what you mean @Çöđěxěŕ this is how you change a static value with reflection, please review your downvote!

Comment: The static variable in the dll is in the Global Stack and not on the regular stack.  Try OR all the BindingFlags options (not just NonPublic and Static) and see if you get results.

Comment: How do you do that? You just don't specify any binding flags? Post this as an answer, I'll tell you if it works

Comment: NonPublic|Static should be enough. Which library are you using? There's not enough information here to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I use a DLL from an internal product, nothing fancy, just a regular DLL with in-house code

Comment: I used reflection for a lot of things and never had a single problem, but it's the first time I try it with a value in another DLL, and it looks like it doesn't work

Comment: The suggestions you've seen should work, even across assemblies, so if they don't, there's something we're not seeing and it's difficult to guess what that could be. You would need to share that code. If you're concerned about sharing proprietary code, anonymize the names and leave out method bodies.

Comment: I've updated the question with more sample, thanks for the comment

Comment: @jdweng There is no such thing as the global stack.

Comment: In c++?????????

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. The only thing I can think of is that it might be that it's running in Medium or Low Trust, or something like that. Using `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static` is indeed sufficient (no need to search public members when you know it's not public).  See if you can find a public, static field (be sure to switch to `BindingFlags.Public`) without doing anything else different. If that works, it's almost certainly a trust/security limitation.